# "Peek/Go to definition" jumps to partial declaration in a tab named as "xxx[from metadata][Read only]"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2015, in a C# solution, when I right click an identity from a library, and select "Peek/Go to definition", it shows its partial declaration instead of complete definition in a tab named as "xxx[from metadata][Read only]".

- I have added the library's dll to the project, so it can build well.
- I have the source files of the library locally, and another different solution can jump to the complete definition of any identity defined in the library.

So do I miss doing something for the solution, in order to be able to jump to the complete definition of an identity in the library?

Comment: "I have the source files of the library locally" - if the code is *referencing* the library, then the code being used is : the library - not your local copy

Comment: Stop adding "thanks" to your many posts.